# What can cause Base64 decoding throw FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, base64

I am using C# and .NET to encode and decode base64 string. The following are snippets of my code:

Base64 encoding:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        …...
    return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Base64 decoding

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(messageBody);
```

My code fails 99% of the time with 1% chance to succeed though. The stack trace is as follows:

*5xx Error Returned:System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.                                                                                                 at System.Convert.FromBase64_ComputeResultLength(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)                                                                                                                                                          at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)                                                                                                                                                                       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)*

Does anyone know what can cause base64 decoding to fail? My encoding and decoding methods are symmetric and I am really confused about what can be the root cause for this issue?

Comment: How are you receiving the `messageBody` variable? Does it contain literal newlines or other non-base64 characters? You need to pass the base64 string and only the base64 string.

Comment: It is via some queuing implementation; we send encoded base64 string to the queue and receive it and consume it via base64 decoding.

Comment: Let me rephrase that, please include the code that loads the `messageBody` variable and an example of the `messageBody` text that is failing. Apparently it contains invalid characters and is causing errors. So the problem is in your transmission of the data or reading of it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. It is crucial that you show us the **exact** value of `messageBody`. When it fails. If you don't know that, I would suggest logging it on failure. Also be sure to log the `Length` of `messageBody` in case there are hidden whitespace characters.

Comment: `What can cause Base64 decoding throw FormatException` It can occur if you ask it to decode a string that is **not** a valid base64 encoded string.

Comment: Print the Base64 encoded message and look at it. Add a test sample to the message. Hint, the Base64 encoded result is a string of printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your replies.

It turned out there were still some old messages in Json format that previously failed in getting delivered and kept retrying in our system; however the new code change of our receiving side got deployed and our receiving side starts to expect messages in protobuf format which results in Deserialization failure when receiving old Json format messages.

Answer (score -2):

In order to debug an issue like this I usually write some tests or create a console app to watch the variables as they change from function to function.

One of the possible scenario's for base64 decoding to fail is if the decoder input is HTMLEncoded. This is common when you pass an encrypted string into a URL for example. It will automatically be HTML encoded and then it sometimes can and sometimes can't be decoded depending on the characters that the encoded output has.

Here's a simple console app to demonstrate this.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "testaa";

        TestEncodeDecode("test");
        TestEncodeDecode("testa");
        TestEncodeDecode("testaa");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void TestEncodeDecode(string input)
    {
        string encoded = Encode(input);

        Console.WriteLine($"Encoded: {encoded}");

        string htmlEncoded = WebUtility.UrlEncode(encoded);

        Console.WriteLine($"htmlEncoded: {htmlEncoded}");

        string decodedString = Decode(htmlEncoded);

        Console.WriteLine($"Decoded: {decodedString}");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static string Decode(string htmlEncoded)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(htmlEncoded);

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return "Decoding failed";
        }
    }

    private static string Encode(string input)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

You'll see that the first two arguments ("test" and "testa") fail to decode, but the third ("testaa") will succeed.

In order to "fix" this, change the Decode method as follows:

```
    private static string Decode(string htmlEncoded)
    {
        try
        {
            string regularEncodedString = WebUtility.UrlDecode(htmlEncoded);
            byte[] decoded = Convert.FromBase64String(regularEncodedString);

            return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded);
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return "Decoding failed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a really bas assumption that the decoded Base64 is ASCII or even any printable string. Base64 is generally used to encode binary to a printable string representation.

Comment: "Base64 is a group of similar binary-to-text encoding schemes that represent binary data in an ASCII string format by translating it into a radix-64 representation." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

I tried to explain how i would tackle an issue like this and gave a working example. How could I have improved my answer?

Comment: The simplest way is to display the Base64 encoded data and visually inspect it and possibly trial decoding it with a site such as [Base64 -> hexadecimal](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/base64.php). No coding required. Example usage code is good but `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decoded);` is a horrible example because it will not work with Base64 encoded non-ASCII data, the usual usage for Base64.